# Autolayout - how to distribute things to proportionally fill screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

In my app, I have four square buttons that I want to proportionally change size for each different screen size that adhere to the margin constraints set. However, I am unable to set a proportional margin size between the trailing edge of the view controller and the leading part of a button, it requires a hard number. How do I get around this. Because i want the app to fit all screen sizes I want the autolayout to measure everything in terms of screen proportions but this doesn't seem possible.

Any advice on how to get around this issue would be much appreciated!

[image: Heres an image of my situation]

Thank you

Comment: use collectionview

Comment: Can you please be more clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you have 4 buttons or 9 buttons? Or are you asking for both cases? Do you want the buttons equally distributed? Or do you want them to change size?

Comment: I want these buttons to be equally distributed on the bottom half of the screen. Obviously for one screen size I can hard code numbers, but I want the buttons and button margins to proportionally change for different screen sizes. For both cases would be ideal! Thanks

Comment: use stack views you will achieve what u want it will automatically adjust according to screen, give constrains to stack

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you trying to give the `programmatically constrain`? 
Still For the top `UIImageView` please embed all the image in the `stackView`. And for the `UIButton` you can use the `UICollectionView`. That's the easiest way I think.

Answer (score 0):

I see you want margins and sizes of the buttons to be relative to screen size. 
I recommend you to set in Interface Builder only margins around the buttons for each [size class](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html). If the number of the buttons is fixed, probably this will be the easiest way to solve you problem.